# Functional Dependencies / Type Families

Tags: haskell, types

With functional dependencies I can constrain type of dependent parameter in a type class using multi-parameter type classes. Just like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, MultiParamTypeClasses,TypeSynonymInstances  #-}

class (Num a, Integral b) => F a b | a -> b where
  f :: a -> b

instance F Int Int where
  f = id

instance F Float Integer where
  f = truncate
```

And everything'll work perfectly.

```
> f (1 :: Int)
1
> f (1.9 :: Float)
1
```

But if I try to write something like

```
instance F Double String where
  f = show
```

I'll get the following compilation error:

```
No instance for (Integral String)
arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Integral String)
In the instance declaration for `F Double String'
```

Is there a way to approach this with type families instead of fundeps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to have something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts  #-}
class Num a => G a where
  type B a
  g :: (Integral (B a)) => a -> B a

instance G Int where
  type B Int = Int
  g = id

instance G Float where
  type B Float = Integer
  g = truncate
```

This example is not directly using a type family, but an *associated type synonym*, which is activated by the same flag. The idea is fairly easy. Instead of explicit giving a second parameter to the typeclass, we define a type synonym, that is filled in with the appropriate type.

This is also my first time to use associated type synonyms, but it seems to be a quite cool feature.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 12):

Basically not, and this actually has nothing to do with functional dependencies (or type families).  Your class definition has

```
class (Num a, Integral b) => F a b
```

which declares that there must be an Integral instance for `b`.  A `String` doesn't have an Integral instance, so you can't have anything of the form `F a String` unless you define

```
-- String is a type synonym for [Char]
instance Integral [Char] where
```

I don't know that this would be sensible in general.  If it would make sense to create an Integral instance for Strings in your system, you would probably want to put a newtype wrapper around String and create the instance for that instead.

Comment: It was just an example. I have no intention of making strings integral or vice versa, I want to constrain type of **b** (parameter, which depends on **a**) to Integral in class definition!

Comment: But you cannot **want** to constrain it and at the same time **want** an instance of F where that constraint is not met! What should the poor compiler do? Make an excemption because it's you?

Comment: I don't want to have an instance of F where constraint isn't met, it is just an example of the error compiler **should** produce. There is nothing wrong! And I wonder if I could rewrite this code(which fails on `F Double String` instance but works with `instance F Int Int` ) using type families.

Comment: I interpreted your question as "This doesn't compile, could I make it compile with AT's instead of FunDeps?".  The part with strings/compiler error is totally irrelevant, it would probably be more clear if you took it out.  Since you included the superclass constraint in the fundep version, it's clear that any AT solution would need to account for them as well.